# RadGrid - Scrolling does not work on mobile devices when ItemTemplate used

Tags: asp.net, html, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a **RadGrid** with attribute RenderMode set to Mobile.
It works just fine and you can scroll vertically fine if I add "rough" data into the ItemTemplate e.g.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("SomeData") %> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

However, if I add some extra tags around the data e.g.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="text-center">
    <%# Eval("SomeData") %>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I can't scroll the data any longer as it behaves like I am dragging the whole control.

It also works fine if you use **GridBoundColumn** instead meaning, only when you add containers into the template column it stops scrolling on **mobile devices**. On desktops still works perfectly fine. Thank you

**NOTE:** I've checked and this question is not already answered. Thx

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but why do you require to have a div? 
Wouldn't it be simpler to either have a telerik-control to hold the bound data inside the item-template?
Like a radlabel and eval / bind the data to the text (assuming it's text).
If you need to add more items than just the one, simply add a table.

Answer (score 0):

To further iterate on my comment, this is how I've dealt with templatecolumns and it's been very successful.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" AllowFiltering="True" runat="server" HeaderStyle-Width="2%"
    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" CurrentFilterFunction="EqualTo" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ShowFilterIcon="False" 
    FilterControlWidth="100%" UniqueName="IDX_Actual" DataField="IDX_Actual" SortExpression="IDX_Actual" 
    GroupByExpression="IDX ID Group By ID">

            <ItemTemplate>

                <telerik:RadLabel ID="RlblIDX" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IDX_Actual") %>' UniqueName="RlblIDX" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The label will then use the ItemStyle to align the text to the center of it's assigned width. 
It's also inside a telerik-control, which by itself gives you further functionality that might (or might not) be nice to have later on.

Furthermore you would be able to set any specific styling-choices with the radlabel's [CSSclass](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/panelbar/appearance-and-styling/setting--the-css-class-of-items)

Happy coding! :)

Comment: I see your point but my problem is that the template itself is little complex having rounded numbers to the left, diff bg color etc. which makes me use containers which btw do not have to be divs. I tried with tables, panels etc. none of them worked on mobile devices.

Comment: I just realized that it does not work even with labels only if you stretch them all over the row (width: 100%) ... there must be something that should be adjusted about the radgrid in order to make the row contents scroll up/down when moved on mobile device.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly you need a solution where you display text (again, I assume it's text). 
But there is so much text that you need to be able to scroll the label because it doesn't wrap it correctly?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about what sort of mobile device you are using. We develop our apps to work both on tablets and desktops / laptops and we have used GridTemplateColumns with tables on multiple occasions.

Comment: I tested on several devices including iPhone 5 and Samsung S6. It always works fine without item template and never works with item template. As mentioned it behaves like i want to drag/move the grid somewhere ... it grabs the entire page. Only if you touch somewhere between the rows it works fine. Weird. I think i will use another control

Comment: So. If I understand it correctly you have an issue where you are attempting to display data in a ItemTemplate but all the data isn't displayed? Most likely because it spans quite far down in the Column?

Comment: I have no issues with displaying the data. Rather I can't scroll the data because it behaves like I am dragging the whole control. Still, the scrollbar is visible.